# Any light configuration for Resharper 7.1?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, stylecop

I am using Resharper 7.1 only because one function "Clean Code..." with StyleCop settings.

I dont need other things like intellisense or new menus (which actually working extremely slowly).

Is it possible to use some external tool to clean code and disable Resharper in visual studio?
Is it possible to confugure Resharper to disable all his "cool" addons and menus like custom "Rename" and use VisualStudio defaults?
Any other tool that can reformat code with style cop settings without such impact on performance?

Comment: Did you try to go over ReSharper | Options? Most options to disable parts of ReSharper are in plain sight there. And why don't you use ReSharper analysis and quick fixes features?

Comment: "ReSharper analysis and quick fixes features" - they are slow. Its almoust impossible to work with this stuff. And i got good PC.And even if everything disabled resharper tooks almoust all memory and adds his own refactor menus that i dont need at all.

Comment: Analysis is a feature that finds errors in your code and suggests how you can quickly fix them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot completely turn off all of the ReSharper features, but if you go to ReSharper | Options you can turn off following things:

1. Environment -> Editor. You can turn off all of the checkboxes. They are responsible for typing assists and can cause typing delays on very slow computers.
2. Environment -> Intellisense -> General. You can select 'Visual Studio' to turn off advanced intellisense features from ReSharper.
3. Code Inspection -> Settings. You can turn off 'Enable code analysis'. It is responsible for finding errors in your code and offering quick fixes for them.
4. Code Editing -> Context Actions and Code Editing -> C# -> Context Actions. You can turn off all of the checkboxes. They are responsible for giving you some of the code editing helpers by Alt-Enter.
5. Tools -> Unit testing. You can turn off "Enable unit testing" checkbox if you don't use ReSharper unit test runner.
6. Maybe you should also delete all of the Todo items patterns from Tools -> To-do items.

But the best thing you can do is to ask your boss to buy you a good development workstation with enough memory and SDD - that would be useful even without ReSharper, because your time is many times more expensive. And learn to use advanced ReSharper features. They are really worth it.

Comment: anyway i have good PC and 8 GB of ram.) But when right click takes 1 second and "rename" dialog load time is 2 seconds this is totaly sucks. When performance of this tool is bad even PC cannot solve this.

Comment: That's strange - on my PC both actions execute immediately, and our project is very big. What kind of project do you have? Do you have other Visual Studio extensions installed, except ReSharper? Try to disable them, there are some extensions known to cause problems with ReSharper. If it still slow, could you be so kind to make a performance snapshot for us (ReSharper | Options | Help | Profile Visual Studio), upload it to dropbox or our ftp and create an issue request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard#newissue=yes ? Many thanks!

Comment: Dmitry Osinovskiy Now everything from Resharper is off. But anyway i will try to send profiling info later.